# scl enable python27 bash

Tags: bash, cron, software-collections

I've hit a snag with a shell script intended to run every 30 minutes in cron on a Redhat 6 server. The shell script is basically just a command to run a python script.

The native version python on the server is 2.6.6 but the python version required by this particular script is python 2.7+. I am able to easily run this on the command line by using the "scl" command (this example includes the python -V command to show the version change):

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
$ scl enable python27 bash
$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

At this point I can run the python 2.7.3 scripts on the command line no problem.

Here's the snag.

When you issue the `scl enable python27 bash` command it starts a new bash shell session which (again) is fine for interactive commandline work. But when doing this inside a shell script, as soon as it runs the bash command, the script exits because of the new session.

Here's the shell script that is failing:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/python/scripts/
scl enable python27 bash
python runAllUpserts.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

It simply stops as soon as it hits line 4 because "bash" pops it out of the script and into a fresh bash shell. So it never sees the actual python command I need it to run.

Plus, if run every 30 minutes, this would add a new bash each time which is yet another problem.

I am reluctant to update the native python version on the server to 2.7.3 right now due to several reasons. The Redhat yum repos don't yet have python 2.7.3 and a manual install would be outside of the yum update system. From what I understand, yum itself runs on python 2.6.x.

Here's where I found the method for using scl

http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/02/14/setting-up-django-and-python-2-7-on-red-hat-enterprise-6-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 29):

Doing everything in one heredoc in the SCL environment is the best option, IMO:

```
scl enable python27 - << \EOF
cd /var/www/python/scripts/
python runAllUpserts.py >/dev/null 2>&1
EOF
```

Another way is to run just the second command (which is the only one that uses Python) in scl environment directly:

```
cd /var/www/python/scripts/
scl enable python27 "python runAllUpserts.py >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

Answer (score 23):

`scl enable python27 bash` activates a python virtual environment.

You can do this from within a bash script by simply sourcing the enable script of the virtual environment, of the SCL package, which is located at `/opt/rh/python27/enable`

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/python/scripts/
source /opt/rh/python27/enable
python runAllUpserts.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: This works well in my experience - only a single line change and the `enable` script is very simple.  To see the path for any collection, use a command like this: `scl enable python27 'which python'`

Answer (score 8):

Isn't the easiest to just your python script directly? `test_python.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
f = open('/tmp/pytest.log','w+')
f.write(sys.version)
f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

then in your crontab:

```
2 * * * *    scl python27 enable $HOME/test_python.py
```

Make sure you make `test_python.py` executable.

Another alternative is to call a shell script that calls the python. `test_python.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash
python test_python.py
```

in your crontab:

```
2 * * * *   scl python27 enable $HOME/test_python.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

One liner

```
scl enable python27 'python runAllUpserts.py >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

I use it also with the devtoolsets on the CentOS 6.x

```
me@my_host:~/tmp# scl enable devtoolset-1.1 'gcc --version'
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 1):

`scl` is the dumbest "let us try and lock you in` nonsense I've seen in a while.

Here's how I made it so I could pass arguments to a series of scripts that all linked to a single skeleton file:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/skeleton
#!/bin/sh

tmp="$( mktemp )"
me="$( basename $0 )"
echo 'scl enable python27 - << \EOF' >> "${tmp}"
echo "python '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/${me}' $@" >> "${tmp}"
echo "EOF" >> "${tmp}"
sh "${tmp}"
rm "${tmp}"
```

So if there's a script you want to run that lives in, say, `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/pepper` you can do this:

```
# cd /usr/bin
# ln -s skeleton pepper
# pepper foo bar
```

and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen this `scl` stuff once before and don't have ready access to a system with it installed.  But I think it's just setting up PATH and some other environment variables in some way that vaguely similar to how they're done under `virtualenv`.

Perhaps changing the script to have the `bash` subprocess call `python` would work:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/python/scripts/
(scl enable python27 bash -c "python runAllUpserts.py") >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The instance of `python` found on the subprocess `bash`'s shell should be your 2.7.x copy ... and all the other environmental settings done by `scl` should be inherited thereby.